# Gradle não reconhece dependência na IDE IntelliJ

Tags: java, gradle

Meu gradle está configurado assim:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    compile project (':core')

    compile group: 'org.fusesource', name: 'sigar', version: '1.6.4',
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.1',
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.1-1',
    testCompile group: 'com.sun.net.httpserver', name: 'http', version: '20070405',
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.5';
}
```

E ele retorna um erro ao atualizar. Estou começando agora, alguém poderia me ajudar? Tô usando o IntelliJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente retirar as "," e o ; no final de cada linha. No gradle, você não precisa disso.

Comment: Eu usava no Eclipse assim, e acho que nunca deu problema. Você acha que pode ser a plataforma?

Comment: Eu acho que você deve estar confundindo com alguma outra coisa. Nem no Eclipse se usa "," ou ";" no final de linha para o Gradle. Bem, pelo menos não na declaração de dependências, que eu me lembre. Você pode estar confundindo com o código, mas lembre-se que são duas coisas separadas. [Aqui](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants?hl=pt-br#dependencies) fala tudo que você precisa saber sobre declaração de dependências no nosso amigo Gradle.